# Use Jolt to filter out specific values from MSFT response

Tags: json, jolt

From the GraphAPI I receive the following (pre-filtered) response, however there are still values that I don't want. I want to keep it as simple as possible, but not sure which approach is the best here. One of the approaches I tried is posted down here.

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('mailbox%40mail.app')/messages(sender,subject,body)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"6xAAAAAAKq\"",
      "id": "6xAAAAAAVQAAA=",
      "subject": "Can we speak tomorrow?",
      "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": "Meeting at 10?"
      },
      "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "test-mail",
          "address": "test-mail@sender.mail.app"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"6xAAAAAAKq\"",
      "id": "6xAAAAAAVQAAA=",
      "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
      "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
      },
      "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "test-mail",
          "address": "test-mail@sender.mail.app"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"6xAAAAAAKq\"",
      "id": "6xAAAAAAVQAAA=",
      "subject": "Nice city",
      "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": "Want to join me on a business trip?"
      },
      "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "test-mail",
          "address": "test-mail@sender.mail.app"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result should look like this:

```json
{
  "Messages": [
    {
      "id": "6xAAAAAAVQAAA=",
      "sender": "test-mail@sender.mail.app",
      "subject": "Can we speak tomorrow?",
      "content": "Meeting at 10?"
    },
    {
      "id": "6xAAAAAAVQAAA=",
      "sender": "test-mail@sender.mail.app",
      "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    {
      "id": "6xAAAAAAVQAAA=",
      "sender": "test-mail@sender.mail.app",
      "subject": "Nice city",
      "content": "Want to join me on a business trip?"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following, but can't really get my head around it.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "value": {
        "*": {
          "id": "value.[&1].id",
          "sender": "value.[&1].sender.emailAddress.address",
          "subject": "value.[&1].subject",
          "body": "value.[&1].sender.emailAddress.address"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to walk through the indices of the **value** list within a shift transformation spec. You can prefer addressing the attributes, which are not in the current object, by **`@(0,elm_at_surr_level.sub_elm_level1.sub_elm_level2)`** reference as key such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "value": {
        "*": {
          "id": "Messages.[&1].&",
          "@(0,sender.emailAddress.address)": "Messages.[&1].sender",
          "subject": "Messages.[&1].&",
          "@(0,body.content)": "Messages.[&1].content"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com is

[image]

If sorting as displayed(*in the order of* `id`->`sender`->`subject`->`content`) needed, then that would be a bit tricky such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "value": {
        "*": {
          "id": "Messages.[&1].&",
          "@(0,sender.emailAddress.address)": "Messages.[&1].sender",
          "subject": "Messages.[&1].&",
          "@(0,body.content)": "Messages.[&1].zontent"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Messages": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.[&1].&",
          "z*": "&2.[&1].c&(0,1)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks. I think I need to add another operation in the bottom to get the sorting right?

Comment: you're welcome @Nick yes, sorting will need an extra spec called `sort` too, such as adding `,{"operation": "sort"}`, but it sorts alphabetically by default.

Comment: Yeah I tried something like this, to get a specific order back.

 ,
  {
    "operation": "short",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "sender": "sender",
      "subject": "subject",
      "content": "content"
    }
  }